# phpthumb not working with bmp file

Tags: php, image, bmp, phpthumb

I am creating thumbnails of image using phpthumb, its working fine for other formates except bmp file. The Method GenerateThumbnail() returning false with bmp image.

Do I need to set any parameter for the this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install imagemagick for the plugin to be able to handle bmp files.

http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/